# How can I get userid using passport-jwt?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm trying to grab the `userid` and add it to a function that runs when the node server fires up. I've tried `axios` and `node-fetch` to send a  `GET` request and grab the id but it's not working. I even tried `app.get("/api/users/current")`

which response with an object that has the id. Am I missing something here? Thanks

```
const userId = "";

module.exports = function mailUser(mailday) {
  console.log("Users fired");

  console.log(userId);



  // axios.get("http://localhost:5001/api/users/current")
  // .then((res) => {
  //   userId = res.id;
  //   console.log(UserId);
  // })
  // .catch((err) => {
  //   console.log(err);
  // });
  // console.log(userId);

  let deffered = Q.defer();

  Coworker.find({ user: userId }).exec((err, coworker) => {
    let coworkers = [];

    if (err) {
      deffered.reject(console.log("failed: " + err));
    } else {
      // Add all users coworkers
      for (let i = coworker.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        coworkers.push(coworker[i]);
      }
      deffered.resolve(coworkers);
    }
    console.log(coworkers);
  });

  return deffered.promise;
};
```

Comment: Please add the code you tried.

Comment: @Ikbel i added the function

Answer (score 0):

I think that You messed up with two things:

- In `axios.get(...)` You invoke `console.log(UserId)` although Your variable is named `userId` with small `u` at the beginning.
- To use `id` from axios response, You need to access it from `res.data` object not from `res` directly.

  ```
  axios.get("http://localhost:5001/api/users/current")
    .then((res) => {
      userId = res.data.id;
      console.log(userId);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
       console.log(err);
    });
  ```

I prefer to use `async/await` with object destrcuturing so it would be:

```
const fetchUserID = async () => {
  const { data: { id: userId } } = await axios.get("http://localhost:5001/api/users/current");
  return userId;
}
```

So in Your code to retrieve `userId`, You just need to invoke that function.

Comment: Hey KarlR thanks for your answer. When I do this I get a long error. Most likely because my server doesn't know anyone is logged in. I'm testing everything with postman and everything seems to be working fine. I'm not sure what else to do but maybe try invoking the function via my client by grabbing the id from the state in React.

Comment: You can paste the error here, so we can try to help You.